terraform validate CSI driver is installed for default storage class
I am looking for a way to validate that CSI driver is installed for default storage class. I have one variable for default storage class var.default_storage_class and have variable var.storage_providers of type list for installed CSI drivers . I tried code below without success.
variable default_storage_class { 
  default = ""
}

variable storage_providers {
   type = list 
   default = ["storage1_iscsi"]
}
   


resource "null_resource" "check_defaultstorageclass_csidriver_is_installed" {
  lifecycle {
    precondition {
      condition     = (var.default_storage_class == "storage1_iscsi" && contains(var.storage_providers, "storage1_csi")) || (var.default_storage_class == "storage2_nfs" && contains(var.storage_providers, "storage2_csi")) || (var.default_storage_class == "longhorn" && contains(var.storage_providers, "longhorn")) || (var.default_storage_class == "lvm-file" && contains(var.storage_providers, "lvm"))
      error_message = "CSI provider for default storage class is not installed"
    }
  }
}


What is the issue with the code you have?

It doesn't throw error in cases where it should, and errors when the inputs matches .

From your last comment it sounds like you should reverse your entire condition, wrap everything in a not statement, like this !(...) I have an example here: https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/blob/dbf53d2bd843981b85b49b8980938bf7fc571d81/TerraForm/var_complex_validation/main.tf#L22 ... try that and test every possible scenario, are you doing unit tests yet? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/tests
